# Remove a filter with JavaScript for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I can't find what I need in any of the answers listed. I'm looking for something simple - remove any filter on the sheet and then clear the values in a specific column. Below is my script. It runs to completion but does not perform the un-filter code, leaving rows that have been filtered not cleared.

```
function resetSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var activecells1 = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getRange("A"+i));}
  activecells1.setValue("").setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Also - if there's a simple line of code that takes me to the bottom of the active cells in A (instead of using A2:A), that would be helpful too so that I don't have to iterate to 500. The code needs to be dynamic enough to run on multiple sheets, though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any Google Reference for dealing with filters by script. Guess, it's not possible.

I think, you could just work with entire range without unfiltering it:

```
var activecells1 = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
activecells1.clear();
```

All cells will be cleared (formatting and values) from range A2:A

Comment: Hi, Max! Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it only clears the text (but not the formatting) of the filtered cells - which is strange to me. Do you know why it would behave this way? Maybe if we answer that question, we can solve the problem. Thanks again!